# Xamarin Forms Force view to bind values

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a view. I have a bindable property there.

```cs
public partial class OrderCard : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty OrderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Order), typeof(Order), typeof(OrderCard), null);

    public Order Order
    {
        get { return (Order)GetValue(OrderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrderProperty, value); }
    }

    public OrderCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In the xaml of this view I'm binding to Order property like this:

```xml
Text="{Binding Order.Name, Source={x:Reference Root}}"
```

Root is a name in the xaml of a view OrderCard

When I use this view in the page everything works ok.

But I want to measure it's size even before adding it to the page.

```cs
var orderCard = new OrderCard { Order = order};
SizeRequest sizeRequest = orderCard.Measure(OrdersContainer.Width/5, OrdersContainer.Height);
```

But it gives me wrong numbers because bindings isn't applied.
How to force to apply bindings when view isn't attached to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by not doing a property Order but passing an order as BindingContext. Then I can measure the size of a view without attaching it to a page like this:

```
var orderCard = new OrderCard { BindingContext = order};
SizeRequest sizeRequest = orderCard.Measure(widthToTryToFitInTheView,heightToTryToFitInTheView);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Binding`s do not require being attached to a `Page` or anything else to be applied.

You might think they're not applied if your method for figuring out is to set a breakpoint on `get_Order` because that is never used, the Xaml loader uses `GetValue` directly. The usual way of figuring out if a Binding is correctly applied, is to add a `PassthroughConverter` (don't look for it, you have to write it yourself) to the `Binding` and put the breakpoint in the `Convert` method.

That being said, you can't `Measure` anything unless it's added to a page that is rendered on screen. If you try to `Measure` before that, you indeed get dummy values.

Comment: Not dummy values. It's measuring everything properly but as it is without applying bindings. Why can't I measure without adding to a page? Measure method receives all that data it needs to measure (I am saying about width and height that view must try to fit in).
but I tried to add it into a page (created dynamically) - nothing changed

Comment: What makes view to check binded values?

Comment: Xaml loader can't do bindings in that case because values to apply come after view is created (after InitializeComponent). I need to force somehow the view to check values. because it don't want to update everything althrough it must do it because here is two way binding and I set a value and all binding must populate a new value